# Cassandra nodes on Google compute engine network ports

Tags: cassandra, google-compute-engine, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to run cassandra(cass_1 & cass_2) on two compute engine(Debian). I am unable to see that the nodes is connected using nod tool status. I have set the seed in case_2 to point to cass_1.

I am guessing that I need to open a port in google compute engine network? Do you know?

Answer (score 1):

Can you give, for each cassandra node, the following info:

- listen_address
- broadcast_address (if set)
- rpc_address (if set)

They are defined in `cassandra.yaml` config file

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by opening the ports in google compute engine firewall.